# Render Control from Model mvc 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model that contain a controller that I generate in the constructor. This example is a bit simplified but it should explain how the model looks

```
public class ContactFormViewModel : ViewUserControl
{
    public ContactFormViewModel()
    {
        ContactCaptchaControl = new CaptchaControl()
        {
            CaptchaLength = 5
        };
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Captcha")]
    public string Captcha { get; set; }

    public CaptchaControl ContactCaptchaControl { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the view looks something like this

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MVC.Models.Contact.ContactFormViewModel>" %>

<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmContact", OnSubmit = "return false;" }))
   {%>
Name:
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "BendsoftTextbox" }) %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) %>

Captcha:
    <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactCaptchaControl) %>

<% } %>
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

My problem is that the control (ContactCaptchaControl) doesn't render as I want to, maybe this is bad practice with mvc?

Any thoughts?

Comment: This seems fine to me.  What do you mean that it doesn't render the way you want?

Comment: The ContactCaptchaControl needs to render in the view, it doesn't